# Connect to linux from WLS and run app in Xming

Tags: xming

I want to open my WSL command prompt on win10 and ssh into my linux machine and run an X11 app and have the window appear in Xming on my win10 machine.

What have I got wrong?

[image]

**Update**

All working from PuTTY, therefore it's a problem with WSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets X applications to show up. Don't know why.

```
laptop $ echo $DISPLAY

laptop $ export DISPLAY=localhost:0
laptop $ ssh -X rwb@imac51
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
Last login: Thu Nov  5 20:50:05 2020 from 192.168.1.11
rwb@imac51:~$ xeyes
```

[image]